# Rails cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, reference

I want to delete something from my database. 
The value references some other tables.

Error is:

```
Mysql2::Error: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

How can I resolve this properly?

If I add some constraints like on delete cascade the other values won't be deleted right?

Edit:

```
def delete
   @vid = Movie.find params[:id]
   @vid.delete
   redirect_to :action => :add
end
```

Update Models

movie.rb

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :ratings
  belongs_to :channel
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  mount_uploader :video, MovieUploader
```

comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :movie
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :rating
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you've created the foreign keys using `ActiveRecord::Migration`, it'll use `ON DELETE RESTRICT` by default (i.e, the opposite of what you want: row entry will be **NOT** deleted if there are entries with references from other tables).

You need to change your migration to use `ON DELETE CASCADE`:

```
class CreateChild < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :child do |t|
      t.references :parent, foreign_key: {on_delete: :cascade}
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 13):

Make sure your parent Model.rb has

```
has_many :model, :dependent => :delete_all
```

this makes sure all your data gets deleted once you delete a parent Model.

Like for instance you have Post.rb and Comment.rb

Post.rb

```
has_many :Comments, :dependent => :delete_all
```

So, When you delete a Post, all corresponding Comments will be deleted as well.

Hope it helped

Cheers

Comment: Thanks but it don't have any effect. error still appears

Comment: how are you deleting it?

Comment: added my delete function oben

Answer (score 4):

**Error:**
 Mysql2::Error: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

**Solution:**

I think you have used .delete or delete_all,

Instead of **.delete or delete_all** use **.destroy**

**.destroy** will delete all associated values with that model

Answer (score 3):

You are using `delete`, from [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-delete):

> To enforce the object's before_destroy and after_destroy callbacks or
>   any :dependent association options, use #destroy.

So you need to use `destroy` instead so that the proper callback from rails to remove dependent records is executed:

```
def delete
   @vid = Movie.find params[:id]
   @vid.destroy
   redirect_to :action => :add
end
```

Because your `Comment` records depend on the `Movie` record that you are trying to delete, hence, since rails is just trying to remove the movie before the comments the database engine complains if there is a foreign key from the comment table to the movie table.

Answer (score 1):

Could you post the applicable database schema?

If you set up a delete cascade constraint, then the other values will be deleted.  If this isn't the desired outcome, then you might need to rethink the referential integrity of the database.

Perhaps, instead you might want to consider using the ActsAsParanoid gem to soft delete the elements instead?

Comment: Error comes from a comments which belongs to a movie. 

Mysql2::Error: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dev`.`comments`, CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_56963e5c80` FOREIGN KEY (`movie_id`) REFERENCES `movies` (`id`)): DELETE FROM `movies` WHERE `movies`.`id` = 1

The comments could be deleted .. so I shoud only add the on delete cascade right?

Comment: If you intend to delete the comments when you delete the movie then yes. You could consider the model looking like so `class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end`